# How to zoom a ImageView to fit screen by the smaller side and display the top of the image?

Tags: android, imageview, resize, zooming, scale

I want to zoom a image until it's smaller side (height or width) fits the screen, even if the higher side gets off the screen, and I want to display the top and the horizontal center of that image
Is that possible?